# Find indicies of string in list of strings for an unsorted list

Tags: python, list, performance, indexing

## Problem Statement

If you are given a string lets call it `target`, can you give me back ALL indicies in which `target` is found in some input list of strings (this is important, it is a list of strings not numbers), lets call it `input_list`. Example inputs:

```
target = '1234'
input_list = [str(x) for x in range(30000)] + [str(x) for x in range(30000)]
```

You can not assume that the `input_list` is sorted if you want to sort the list you will need to add that to your own version of `benchmarkFind()`. The simple solution is to just do the following but this can be very inefficient:

```
def benchmarkFind(target,input_list):
    out = []
    for i in range(len(input_list)):
        if input_list[i] == target:
            out.append(i)
    return out
```

The answer here would be:

```
idx = [1234, 31234]
```

## Benchmark Results

```
>>> %timeit benchmarkFind(target,input_list)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.07 ms per loop
```

## User Comment Results

From @trincot and @Abhinav Sood - Slightly better but not great.

```
def enumerateFind(target,input_list):
    return [i for i, e in enumerate(input_list) if e == target]

>>> %timeit enumerateFind(target,input_list)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.96 ms per loop
```

From @B. M - This looks to be the **best answer thus far**!

```
def primitiveFind(target ,input_list):
    try :
        l=[]
        u=-1
        while True:
            u = input_list.index(target,u+1)
            l.append(u)
    except ValueError:
        return l

>>> %timeit primitiveFind(target,input_list)
1000 loops, best of 3: 577 µs per loop
```

Comment: If you are going to return the whole list then there is no advantage in creating a generator. Did you try `[i for i, val in enumerate(input_list) if val == target]`?

Comment: @trincot yes. Although it is true that this is usually faster, and it is, not by much. I have updated the problem statement to clear things up and provided an example with your suggestion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Fastest way to find Indexes of item in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640780/python-fastest-way-to-find-indexes-of-item-in-list)

Comment: Timing results really depend on how sparse the list is with respect to the searched value. See also [this answer and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18669080/5459839). Any way this has been asked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python loops are known to be slow, but primitive on list are fast. `list.index` is fast.

```
def find2(target ,input_list):
    try :
        l=[]
        u=-1
        while True:
        u= input_list.index(target,start=u+1)
        l.append(u)
    except ValueError:
        return l
```

runs:

```
In [32]: find2(target,input_list)
Out[32]: [1234, 31234]

In [33]: %timeit find2(target,input_list)
2.8 ms ± 255 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [34]: %timeit benchmarkFind(target,input_list)
12 ms ± 1.35 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [35]: %timeit [i for i, e in enumerate(input_list) if e == target]
14.2 ms ± 1.79 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

4x faster on my computer this morning.

**EDIT**

For further tuning, data alignement is important, numpy arrays is a good way to achieve that. Unfortunately, the conversion from list is costly, so this make  sense if the data can be supplied in array form :

```
input_arr=np.array(input_list)

(input_arr==target).nonzero()
(array([ 1234, 31234], dtype=int64),)

%timeit input_arr=np.array(input_list)
10.6 ms ± 414 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit (input_arr==target).nonzero()
1.56 ms ± 123 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Good comment, yea can never stray too far from the primitives! I provided a working example of your comment above and it does look to be the fasted approach so far! Please see my updated "User Comment Results" section in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Enumeration is way faster:

```
python -m timeit -s "\
    target = '1234';\
    input_list = [str(x) for x in range(30000)] + [str(x) for x in range(30000)];\
    idx = [i for i, e in enumerate(input_list) if e == target]"
```

100000000 loops, best of 3: **0.00582 usec** per loop

Comment: @Abbhinav I am not sure where you are seeing that kind of performance, but that is not right> please see my updated "User Comment Results" section in my post. Enumeration is generally faster yes, but not by much.

Comment: @walsha2 I am running this on Python 3.6.5 from Anaconda (with GCC 7.2.0) on a RHEL Linux machine with 24G memory. I ran this again, and still see roughly the same time: `100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.00585 usec per loop`

Comment: Still can not recreate this with similar machine. That time can not be right. Plus that time is inconsistent with everything that was reported above and in other questions. I think the correct answer is still what B.M. posted.

Comment: That's so weird, but great looking at the comparisons between different techniques. Also, I would recommend using the same number of iterations for all possible solutions that you're evaluating.