# Python: more efficiently get the index of item in list

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples (example below) and need to find the index of an item. 
At present I am using list.index() but given the size of dataset and frequency of use its proving slow. Is there a more efficient solution?

**Dataset example:**
The data I am using is a tuple of locations

`[(21, 31, 30), (20, 30, 29), (20, 30, 31), (20, 30, 30)......]`

Thank you

Comment: Your usage of `index` suggests that the tuples are unique. Why not use a dict then? In other words, *why* do you need the index? what significance does it have?

Comment: this answer works for you  : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53303488/6451573 (tuples are hashable so they can be keys)